# MongoDB check if key value exists and update only some fields

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, nosql, crud

Let's say I have a MongoDB collection "people" that has the form

```json
[
  {
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_1],
    name: "Paul",
    hobby: "rowing",
    fixed: 1
  },
  {
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_2],
    name: "Selena",
    hobby: "drawing",
    fixed: 2
  },
  {
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_3],
    name: "Emily",
    hobby: "jogging",
    fixed: 3
  }
]
```

And new data to be inserted of the form

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "Paul", // name exists, so keep "fixed" at 1
    hobby: "archery",
    fixed: 4
  },
  {
    name: "Peter",
    hobby: "knitting",
    fixed: 5
  }
]
```

I would like to insert/update the collection with the new data. However, if a document with the same "name" already exists, I do not want to update "fixed". The result after inserting the above data should be

```json
[
  {
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_1],
    name: "Paul",
    hobby: "archery", // updated
    fixed: 1 // not updated, because name existed
  },
  {
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_2],
    name: "Selena",
    hobby: "drawing",
    fixed: 2
  },
  {
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_3],
    name: "Emily",
    hobby: "jogging",
    fixed: 3
  },
  { // newly inserted document
    _id: [OBJECT_ID_4],
    name: "Peter",
    hobby: "knitting",
    fixed: 5
  }
]
```

The data includes a large number of documents, so I would like to achieve this in one query if possible. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bulkWrite  with  updateOne's   with $upsert:true  seems to work best for you...

Answer (score 0):

bulkWrite not perform a Find operation.
Its (in my case) is necessary to control if it will create a another document.
In my case I just use find check before insert/create method.

```
if (collection.find({"descr":descr}).limit(1).length === 1) {
 //...create method
  console.log('Exists')
   }
```

Comment: The question is about updating, thus @R2D2's answer is the way to go...